# How to match strings in cells on Excel, with if/or operators, and delete the rows

Tags: vba, excel

Disclaimer: I've never used Visual Basic and I've never made a macro.

I am trying to create a macro in Microsoft Excel 2010 that will delete all rows where neither column G nor column I contain the string "Ohio", "Indiana", or "Kentucky". To clarify, the row should be deleted if the cell does not contain either of those three state names. I want the macro to start at row 6, as rows 1-5 contain vital information. The whole sheet contains over 14000 rows and only ~1.5% of those are actually helpful.

Also, I am looking to be able to reuse this macro, but for other terms (besides Ohio, Indiana, and Kentucky) in other columns (besides G and I).

It may also help me if you can, besides correcting this, explain what exactly I am saying in these lines. Perhaps in Java terms, or Python is okay too. Not necessary, but may help.

```
Sub DeleteIfNotKYINOH()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 6 Step -1
```

I get a type mismatch error on the next line.

```
If Cells(i, "G").Value = "Ohio" Or "Indiana" Or "Kentucky" Then
Cells(i, "G").Value = True
End If
If Cells(i, "I").Value = "Ohio" Or "Indiana" Or "Kentucky" Then
Cells(i, "I").Value = True
End If
If Cells(i, "G").Value Or Cells(i, "I").Value = False Then
Cells(i, "G").EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
' DeleteIfNotKYINOH Macro
' Delete all rows that do not contain Ohio, Indiana, or Kentucky, as a state.
'

'
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you record it. Use Autofilter.

Comment: Your type mismatch error is due to the `Or` format.  Each `Or` needs to be it's own statement that evaluates to `True` or `False` like this: `If Cells(i, "G").Value = "Ohio" Or Cells(i, "G").Value = "Indiana" Or Cells(i, "G").Value = "Kentucky" Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to consider, it looks like you are on the right track, though, you even got the backwards iteration over the collection (this stumps a lot of people!).

Make sure to declare your variables properly (`i` and `LastRow` should probably be Long integer, not unspecified Variant type).

`If` statements can include `Or` joins, but have to be like this:

```
If Cells(i, "G").Value = "Ohio" Or Cells(i, "G").Value  = "Indiana" Or Cells(i, "G").Value  = "Kentucky"
```

Since you want to be able to re-use the macro for other strings, of course you could go in and edit each instance of "Ohio" or "Indiana", etc., but that can be tedious and error-prone.

You could do something like this instead to re-use it for a list of any number of states, just change the assignment to the `states` variable.

```
Const states as String = "Ohio,Indiana,Kentucky"
Sub TestDeleteIfNot()
Dim i as Long, LastRow as Long
Dim cl as Range

LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 6 Step -1
    With Cells(i, "G")
        If Not(InList(.Value, states)) And Not(InList(.Offset(0,2).Value, states))
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

This routine calls on a function `InList` which accepts as its arguments two strings. The first string should be the value being compared, and the second is a comma-delimited "list" of allowable values.

```
Function InList(strVal as String, list as String) As Boolean
Dim a as Variant
For each a in Split(list, ",")
    If strVal = a Then
        InList = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

The function converts the list to an array and iterates that against the compare value.   It should return `False` if the value is not found. So then the logic in the calling sub runs this on cells in COlumn G and also Column I, only deleting the row if BOTH tests return False.

Comment: Plus one for extra mile of explanation and walk through. Btw, why create a string and then a function. Wouldn't it take less time to pass the list directly to `Array` then use `Application.Match`?

Comment: @L42 from my POV (and probably most people) it's easier for a human to instantiate a string (and then use the `Split` function to convert it to an array), rather than to dimension an array and specify each item.  But that may be just personal preference. As for the iteration versus the `Match` function, see Tim's response [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18769246/1467082).

Comment: Cool. I'm curious as well that I asked. :) Btw, when I say array, I mean like this `arr = Array("Ohio","Indiana","Kentucky")` where `arr` is declared as variant.

Comment: @L42 Ahhh yeah you could do that or you could simply send `Array("Ohio","Indiana","Kentucky")` to the function, etc.  Just depends on your needs I guess. For me, this sort of thing is *usually* a constant definition list, but since you can't declare arrays as Constant, I use the `As String` method and `Split` to an array. I'm not saying the other way is wrong, only that this is how I would typically approach it. Cheers.