# Need help, Excel Formula, Count number of cells in a range that match the content of a different range

Tags: arrays, excel, count, formula, vba

I am pretty good on Excel but this has got me.

I have a range of entries - $D7:$AH7

I want to know how many times these entries appear in this range - $K$7:$V$10

I have tried countif array but I think it is trying to match row with row rather than each entry in my range against the entire lookup range. I also tried transposing the lookup range onto the same line but then I think it tries to match column by column in the same fashion.

If sumproduct works I can't use that is too calculation extensive with this document.

I am happy to use a VBA solution if you have that suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Non VBA solution:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($K$7:$V$10,$D7:$AH7))
```

**VBA solution:**

Founds how many times values from `rng1` appears in `rng2`:

> Can it ignore blanks?

**UPD:**

```
Function countEntries(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Long
    Dim arr1, arr2, a1, a2

    arr1 = rng1.Value
    arr2 = rng2.Value

    For Each a1 In arr1
        If Trim(a1) <> "" Then
            For Each a2 In arr2
                If a2 = a1 Then
                    countEntries = countEntries + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

call it like this: `=countEntries($D7:$AH7,$K$7:$V$10)`.

---

P.S. I use loop for determining whether array contains value or not rather than `Application.Match/Application.CountIf` because it's up to 10 times faster. See this link for details: [Matching values in string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754096/matching-values-in-string-array/18769246#18769246)

Comment: This VBA solution is awesome but is also matching blanks which causes me a problem. Can it ignore blanks?

Comment: simoco.... I'm no VBA expert but have just made the following adjustment to account for blank entries. If you have a better solution than this edit please let me know. Thanks for your help either way, got me out of a bind ;)                                If a2 = "" Then
            ' do nothing
            Else

Comment: yeah, `If a2 = "" Then` is pretty good, but it seems that it'd be slightly better to add same condition for `a1`. See my updated answer