# Extract from multidimensional array

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array `dat` that shows `Type = Variant/Variant(0 to 500, 0 to 0, 0 to 1)`

There is a "column" of dates:

```
dat(0, 0, 0) = #1/1/2013#
dat(1, 0, 0) = #1/2/2013#
```

I want to extract this set of dates.  I tried:

```
Dim dat As Variant
Dim dt As Variant
'stuff gets dat in the format described above
dt = Application.Index(dat, 0, 1, 1)
```

Unfortunately this gives me an Error 13 Type Mismatch.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **Loop**

```
Sub dural()
    Dim dat(0 To 500, 0 To 1, 0 To 1) As Variant

    dat(0, 0, 0) = #1/1/2013#
    dat(1, 0, 0) = #1/2/2013#

    Dim dt(0 To 500) As Variant

    For i = 0 To 500
        dt(i) = dat(i, 0, 0)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had decided on.  I wasn't sure if there was a clever way to do it without the loop.

Comment: @JeffreyKramer I could be mistaken but I *think* `Application.Index` only works on 2-d arrays and then only if they are base-1. (It's been a while since I tried to use it...). As for looping arrays, it's ugly/cumbersome to code, but generally more efficient than using `Application` level functions. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754096/matching-values-in-string-array) is one such example demonstrating that loop/iteration is up to 10x faster than using the `Application.Match` function on a vector array!