# VBA list reference to

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I would like to store a multi-dimenension list into memory in excel VBA to preform a look up function.  Using an vendor id, which can be alpha numeric, return three other values associate with that vendor.  Use a mailing address as an example. I have a list of all vendors that I do business with along with their mailing address.  When creating an invoice for these vendors, I want to be able to lookup/ refer to their mailing address line 1 , line 2 , zip code etc based upon their name.

The data is stored as

```
"Abc Corportation", 123 main st, New York, New York, 12345  
"My Company", 456 not here, Buffalo , Newy York, 12367  
etc.
```

When creating the bill, I have `"Abc Corportation"` and I want to return the `123 Main st, new york new york.`

I would prefer not having to create an loop to scan through the list each time I want to lookup a vendor address.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We aren't here to write code for you, but to help correct problematic code.

Comment: You can store these pairs in an array, a collection, or a dictionary.  While you may prefer to avoid iteration over an array, [it is actually up to 10x faster than using the `Application.Match` function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754096/matching-values-in-string-array).

Comment: Take a look at storing this information in a `Dictionary` object, where the `Key` is your vendor name, and the `Value` is the comma-delimited address. [Using Dictionary Object in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)

Comment: But the broader question is how you intend to implement this, i.e., how you will *get* these values in to memory. If they're coming from the workbook itself, seems easier (although maybe not faster) to just use VLOOKUP.

Comment: @DavidZemens Good point. The assumption I have is `in-memory` really means `in-memory`, not necessarily stored in the workbook itself. If this is the case then native Excel `VLOOKUP` may be ideal for simplicity sake.

Comment: But where are you *getting* the values from? You'll have to instantiate this `in-memory` list somehow. You can't **save** the list  in memory to persist indefinitely... And when it is out of scope, you'll have to re-instantiate it (from a file source).

Comment: To Adam:  I can load it into an array and loop through it with each pass but worst case scario, 1,000 vendors * 1,000 invoices = 1,000,000 passes.  Where if I can use a string as the key such as PHP does, it would reduce it down to 1,000 iterations.

Comment: @DavidZemens With regard to the speed difference, I agree about using Match against a VBA array; but it seems to run faster than iteration when using it against a range object.  Does that agree with your findings?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I haven't tested it. It's normally the case that performing operations in memory are less expensive than the same/similar operations carried out on objects. It may seem cumbersome, but it's probably faster to store the range `.Value` in an array (that can typically be done in one statement like: arrayValues = Range("A1:D10000").Value`) and iterate the array, rather than using the worksheet function methds.  But I have not tested it for performance and it may be the case that the sheet functions are optimized. Let me know what you find out if you do test it!!

Comment: @DavidZemens When I tested it here (and I used worksheetfunction.match; not application.match), it ran about twice as fast using .match on the range compared with iterating through the array (using a Do loop and incrementing the pointer inside the loop.  (Using .match on a 2D array was much slower, as you found). If your findings were different, I'd want to compare the specifics of how we each tested.  That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Props to David Zemens for his answer / question, vlookup is the way to go as long as the data is format with the index in the left most column.

```
 aValue = "ABC Company"

 answer = ""

 Dim myRange As Range
 On Error Resume Next
 Set myRange = Worksheets("Vendor Lookup").Range("A1:D99")
 answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(aValue, myRange, 2, False)
 If answer <> "" Then MsgBox (answer)
```

Thanks all for the quick repsonses.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin -- First: Congrats on finding your own solution!  I hope you don't mind if I show you a few things here, based on your original solution.

With something like this problem, there are going to be more than a few ways to do it. Rather than show you other ways, I just wanted to show you a few ways to improve your existing solution.

First and foremost, declare *all* variables, and type them as strongly as allows. This helps avoid hard-to-find errors. On a related note, using `Option Explicit` at the top of each module will help enforce this. While it sometimes seems a PITA to declare *everything*, it's much more inconvenient to spend *hours* debugging simply typographical errors.

**NOTE:** In some other languages like python, a line like this implies that `answer` is of type `string`.

```
answer = ""
```

However, in vba, any undeclared variable is of type `Variant`, which can essentially be anything. The following two lines will **not** raise any errors in VBA:

```
answer = "hello, world!"
Set answer = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
```

If you must use `On Error Resume Next` make sure you also do `On Error Goto 0` at the earliest possible line to resume normal error-handling, but it is generally preferable to trap and program around anticipated/known error conditions.

I declare `answer` as Variant (not as String) in order to use the `Application.Vlookup` function which differs slightly from the `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`. The latter will raise error a 1004 error if the value is not found, whereas `Application.Vlookup` will return an error-type value, which can be more aptly tested for than using the clunky `On Error Resume Next`.

```
Dim answer as Variant
Dim aValue as String
Dim myRange as Range

aValue = "ABC Company"
Set myRange = Worksheets("Vendor Lookup").Range("A1:D99")
answer = Application.Vlookup(aValue, myRange, 2, False)
If Not IsError(answer) Then MsgBox answer
```