# Excel formula to get a volatile increment value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, formulas

Could someone here provide me a **non-VBA method** to obtain a formula where its output will increase by 1 whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet? The formula is allowed to use any cells on the worksheet.

The best I can get to perform such a thing is to use the following volatile UDF:

```
Public Num As Long

Public Function INC() As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Num = Num + 1
    INC = Num
End Function
```

Comment: You could turn on iterative calculation, set the maximum number of iterations to 1 and then just enter `=A1+1` in A1.

Comment: Could you post those steps into an answer @Rory? Just to make sure, its output must behave like a volatile function.

Comment: Try it and see. If it does what you need, I'll put it in as an answer. ;)

Comment: Geez, are you being serious @pnuts? What kind of person are you?

Comment: @pnuts Did you just downvote [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38571256/3397819)? If so, could you tell me the reason?

Comment: @Rory I tried your advice and it works. Many thanks. Could you please write an answer to this question? I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly simply with **iterative calculation**. You could turn on iterative calculation in the Formulas section of Options, set the maximum number of iterations to 1 and then just enter `=A1+1` in A1