# issue with arrays with large number of values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare values in arrays after storing fields values from Excel sheet. I am getting error in this line -

`If Trim(wsA.Cells(6, 116 + x).Value) = Trim(myArray1(i, 1).Value) Then`

> (424: Object required)

There are around 80000 values in columns A and D in PO file which I am storing in arrays myArray1 and myArray2.

The complete code is below: Request your help, Thanks

```
Sub UpdateQtyFrmPO()



StartTime = Timer

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


Allocfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xl*; *.csv), *xl*;*.csv", _
                                        Title:="Select the allocation file ")

If Not (Allocfile <> False) Then

MsgBox "Allocation file not selected. Update Aborted!", vbCritical


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True


Exit Sub

End If


Workbooks.Open Allocfile

Set Alloc = ActiveWorkbook

Set wsA = Alloc.ActiveSheet


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''



POfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xl*; *.csv), *xl*;*.csv", _
                                        Title:="Select the PO tracker file ")

If Not (POfile <> False) Then

MsgBox "PO tracker file not selected. Update Aborted!", vbCritical


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True


Exit Sub

End If


Workbooks.Open POfile

Set PO = ActiveWorkbook

Set wsP = PO.ActiveSheet

'''''''''''''
Dim myArray1 As Variant
Dim myArray2 As Variant
Dim myArray3 As Variant

lastrowP = wsP.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowA = wsA.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row


wsA.Range("DM7:DT" & lastrowA).ClearContents


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

myArray1 = wsP.Range("A1:A" & lastrowP).Value
myArray2 = wsP.Range("D1:D" & lastrowP).Value

myArray3 = wsA.Range("A1:A" & lastrowA).Value



  For i = 1 To UBound(myArray1) ''''Job No

  For j = 1 To UBound(myArray2) ''''Article

  For k = 1 To UBound(myArray3) ''''ItemNo


    If myArray3(k, 1) = myArray2(j, 1) Then


      For x = 1 To 8
      wsA.Activate
      If Trim(wsA.Cells(6, 116 + x).Value) = Trim(myArray1(i, 1).Value) Then

      Cells(k, 116 + x).Select

      wsA.Cells(k, 116 + x).Value = Range("O" & i).Value

      End If

      Exit For

      Next x

    End If

    Next k

    Next j

  Next i
```

Comment: Does it work with a small amount of values?

Comment: An array element does not have a `value` property.

Comment: @jamheadart Thanks for comment. It is throwing same error with around 9000 values.

Comment: If that is your complete code then you are not using `Option Explicit`. On the other hand, if you are using `Option Explicit` then this isn't your complete code and you are using global variables. Either way, you are not following good VBA practices.

Comment: It should throw the same error with 2 values. Size has nothing to do with it. @SJR points out the core problem.

Comment: The reason I asked is because your title made it seem like you'd had it working for small arrays, but like others have pointed out, it won't work even with just a few values. Try changing `Trim(myArray1(i, 1).Value)` to `Trim(myArray1(i, 1))`

Comment: I highly recommend to indent and format your code properly. Your code gets much easier to maintain.

Comment: I have seen use of .value with array variant in another post in stackoverflow.
Could you guys please have a look what am I missing here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322557/fastest-vlookup-in-worksheet-data-performed-in-vba

Comment: @shrinivasiyer The post you linked does not use `array.value` and arrays do not have a  `.Value` that is a fact. I think you are mixing something up. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables properly
2. Check your line `Exit For` this will exit the `x` loop on every `x = 1` already.
3. Arrays don't have a `.Value` so `myArray1(i, 1).Value` does not exist and it must be `myArray1(i, 1)`.
4. Indent your code properly.
5. Make sure you don't use `ActiveWorkbook` if you don't have to (check the code below how do do it properly).
6. `A1000000` is not the last cell in column A. Never hardcode these numbers if you can read them `wsP.Rows.Count` gives you the max number of rows.
   And therefore `wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` is the last used cell in column A.
7. Make sure **all** your `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns` objects have a worksheet/workbook specified. Otherwise you might get unwanted results because Excel is picking the wrong worksheet.

I could not check the behavior of your code but the following is at least fixing the obvious issues. Check it out.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateQtyFrmPO()
    Dim StartTime As Single
    StartTime = Timer

    Dim Allocfile As Variant
    Allocfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xl*; *.csv), *xl*;*.csv", _
                                        Title:="Select the allocation file ")

    If VarType(Allocfile) = vbBoolean And Allocfile = False Then
        MsgBox "Allocation file not selected. Update Aborted!", vbCritical
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Alloc As Workbook
    Set Alloc = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Allocfile)

    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Set wsA = Alloc.ActiveSheet

    Dim POfile As Variant
    POfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xl*; *.csv), *xl*;*.csv", _
                                        Title:="Select the PO tracker file ")

    If VarType(POfile) = vbBoolean And POfile = False Then
        MsgBox "PO tracker file not selected. Update Aborted!", vbCritical
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim PO As Workbook
    Set PO = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=POfile)

    Dim wsP As Worksheet
    Set wsP = PO.ActiveSheet



    Dim myArray1 As Variant
    Dim myArray2 As Variant
    Dim myArray3 As Variant

    Dim LastRowP As Long
    LastRowP = wsP.Cells(wsP.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim LastRowA As Long
    LastRowA = wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    wsA.Range("DM7:DT" & LastRowA).ClearContents


    myArray1 = wsP.Range("A1:A" & LastRowP).Value
    myArray2 = wsP.Range("D1:D" & LastRowP).Value
    myArray3 = wsA.Range("A1:A" & LastRowA).Value

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(myArray1) ''''Job No
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(myArray2) ''''Article
            Dim k As Long
            For k = 1 To UBound(myArray3) ''''ItemNo

                If myArray3(k, 1) = myArray2(j, 1) Then
                    Dim x As Long
                    For x = 1 To 8
                        'wsA.Activate
                        If Trim$(wsA.Cells(6, 116 + x).Value) = Trim$(myArray1(i, 1)) Then
                            'wsA.Cells(k, 116 + x).Select
                            wsA.Cells(k, 116 + x).Value = wsA.Range("O" & i).Value
                        End If

                        Exit For 'this will exit always on x=1 and should probably move up right before End If
                    Next x
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that you have 4 nested loops. If there are many rows in your worksheets then nested rows can easily run for a very long time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.